# Show a notification at login using pam_exec

Tags: 12.04, xorg, notification, pam, zenity

This simple script will show a Zenity notification when the user logs in:

```
case "$PAM_TYPE" in
    'open_session' )
    if [ "$PAM_SERVICE" = "lightdm" ] ; then
            DISPLAY=:0 sudo -u $PAM_USER notify-send "Hello there!" "Hello"
        else
            echo "Hello there!"
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

However, this will only work if the DISPLAY variable is actually 0. And won't work for terminal or remote (ssh) logins (obviously, the echo there seems to go nowhere). What can I do about this?

I need a way to:

- Get the current DISPLAY variable from the pam_exec environment, if I'm using a graphical login interface
- Get the current console device, or anywhere where I can send a message to the correct console, if I'm using a console interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist more easy way to send notifications on login (without knowing your DISPLAY variable or using `tty` command to identify your terminal).

In order to send some notification during GNOME or other Desktop Environment start you must create `/etc/xdg/autostart/foobar.desktop` file which calls your script with `notify-send "Hello there!" "Hello"`. Check `/etc/xdg/autostart/` for examples. You can make a copy of the existing `.desktop` file, rename it and modify for your needs. You can also add `X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=XX` parameter to set `XX` seconds delay for your task. If you need to add this only for the selected user, use `~/.config/autostart/` of that user to place your `.desktop` file and check with `gnome-session-properties` that this launcher is active.

In order to send the notification on terminal or ssh login you can use the script placed to `/etc/profile.d/` or send this notification, adding `echo "My Message"` to `/etc/bash.bashrc` directly. Both of them are called from `/etc/profile` and will be run on every login to interactive shell, be it virtual terminal or ssh login. For the selected user use `~/.bash_login` of that user and put the desired message there. **Note:** usage of `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bash_login` makes sense if the default `bash` shell is used; if the user invokes some other shell, for example `/bin/sh/`, these files will be ignored.

Comment: `tty` won't work, if I run `tty > /tmp/out`, I always get a `Not a tty!` message on that file (it's in Spanish originally, maybe the text is not exactly the same). After the login process is over, I can run `tty` and it will work, though.
As for the DISPLAY variable thing, I'll take a look for the convenience, thanks!

Comment: Not a problem. You've got autostart options for interactive shells also, not only for GNOME session. Check 'man bash', INVOCATION section. Actually, even no 'tty' command is needed. You can create ~/.bash_login and put 'echo "My Message"' into it. This script is executed on every login in any virtual terminal.

Comment: I've followed your advice. Now, the `pam_exec` script only writes a file with the values needed for display.
Then, a script located at `/etc/profile.d/` displays the message on the console. I'm using this instead of `~/.bash_login` because I shouldn't write on the users home.
And a script called from a `.desktop` file on `/etc/xdg/autostart` displays the message on the graphical sessions.
Can you expand your answer explaining all this so I can grant you the bounty? Thank you!